# Updated features from GDB after Check-out Replica created from ArcSDE GDB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, replication

I have created Check-out Replica from the main ArcSDE GDB. I have below questions.

If GDB Admin update few things (Attribute or Spatial) after version was created, will it be reflected in the child versions.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad because it is asking three questions rather than the one question per question as described in our [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  I recommend that you edit your question to ask just the most important one first, and then to research/ask the others separately.

Comment: @user34810 - Please perform the following and I can answer your questions: Separate your questions 1 & 2 onto different question pages to satisfy the rules PolyGeo mentioned. For question 2, specify the destination (checkout) geodatabase type (ArcSDE, Personal, File GDB) as well as what type of stats you are looking for? # of Changes? File Size or Row Count?